# Laurent series of an integral with parameter

Tags: divergent-series, laurent-series, regularization

To find the Laurent series of function $f(a)$ at point $a=0$
$$
f(a)=\int^1_0 \frac{d x}{x^2+a^2}
$$
one can first do the integral 
$$
f(a)=\frac{1}{a}\arctan(1/a)
$$
then expand $\arctan(1/a)$ and obtain
$$
f(a)\approx \frac{\pi}{2a}-1+O(a^2).
$$
However if one expands the integrand before integration, 
one would get divergent integral.

My question is: is there any method helping us expand the function $f(a)$ before performing the integral?
The motivation arises from more complicated cases, when the functions can not be integrated out analytically.

==========================================

Updated: I think I find the solution to this integral. When I expand the function $f(a)$, I have to expand all the integral, not only the integrand 
$$
\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\approx \frac{1}{x^2}+O(a^2)
$$
which means that the upper limit of integral has also to be changed, i.e.
$$
f(a)\approx \int^1_a d x\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+O(a^2)\right)
$$
this gives us
$$
f(a)\approx \frac{13}{15 a}-1+O(a^2)
$$
Except the coefficient of $a^{-1}$, all the other orders are consistent.

Comment: Can you explain how exactly you expand the integrand?

Comment: @Batominovski, $1/(x^2+a^2)\approx 1/x^2-a^2/x^4+O(a^3)$, so every terms are divergent at lower limit.

Comment: That's the expansion around $x=\infty$ (valid in complex analysis). The expansion around $x=0$ is given by
$$\frac{1}{a^2+x^2} = \frac{1}{a^2} \frac{1}{1+x^2/a^2} = \frac{1}{a^2} \left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{a^2} + O(x^4) \right) = \frac{1}{a^2} - \frac{x^2}{a^4} + O(x^4)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Expanding the integrand with respect to $a$ round $a\sim 0$
$$
\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{ a^{2n}}{x^{2n+2}}
$$
Step 2: Deforming the integral
$$
\int^\infty_0 dx \to \int^\infty_{\epsilon a} dx
$$
Step 3: Performing the integral
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n a^{2n}\int^\infty_{\epsilon a} \frac{dx}{x^{2n+2}}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{a^{2n}}{2n+1}
+\frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)\epsilon^{2n+1}}
$$
The second term is nothing else but ${\rm arccot}(\epsilon)/a$.

Step 4: Taking the limit $\epsilon \to 0$

$${\rm arccot}(\epsilon)/a\to \pi/(2a)$$
and
$$f(a) = \frac{\pi}{2a}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{a^{2n}}{2n+1}$$